# Comments of a question in Review Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

It just caught my eye this morning that going through the Reopen Votes Queue that for a given question it just shows the question. I think the only queue that shows anything more than the question is the Closed Vote queue; which shows the question and the comments.

Is it worth while to possibly add the comments to any of the other queues? One right off that I can think of would be the Reopen Votes queue. I would not think it would be deciding factor on whether a given question should be open, but could provide context on what change was made to the question.

Comment: In First Posts and Late Answers you can comment, which can also count as a form of review. Not only are comments displayed in those queues, notifications of newly added comments work there as well.

Comment: Ok, those queues are usually cleared by the time I get into the queues.